# Unable to install nose testing framework

Tags: python, testing, nose

I attempted installing **nose** using pip but the installation was terminated with the following error message:

```
    Downloading/unpacking nose
  Downloading nose-1.3.0.tar.gz (404Kb): 286Kb downloaded
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 104, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 245, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 985, in prepare_files
    self.unpack_url(url, location, self.is_download)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1109, in unpack_url
    retval = unpack_http_url(link, location, self.download_cache, self.download_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 451, in unpack_http_url
    download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 368, in _download_url
    chunk = resp.read(4096)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 561, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
timeout: timed out
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pypl has been a little bit slow today. Maybe try [--use-mirrors](http://jacobian.org/writing/when-pypi-goes-down/) to see if it helps alleviate the situation.

> pip
>
> If you’re using a recent pip (0.8.1 or later) use the —use-mirrors
>   flag:
>
> pip install --use-mirrors $PACKAGE
>
> You can also set the PIP_USE_MIRRORS environment variable.
>
> This’ll automatically query the list of mirrors and keep trying until
>   one responds. It can take a bit of time when PyPI’s down as it waits
>   for PyPI to time out, but it’ll work.
>
> For older versions of pip, or if you want to force the use of a
>   particular mirror, use:
>
> pip install -i http://d.pypi.python.org/simple $PACKAGE
>
> If you want to instruct pip to always use the mirror — good if you’ll
>   be doing a lot of installation, or if you’re using pip as part of a
>   bigger automation tool — then put:
>
> [global] index-url = http://d.pypi.python.org/simple
>
> Into ~/.pip/pip.conf.

(you can see that you timed out in the download - top and bottom lines)

> Downloading nose-1.3.0.tar.gz (404Kb): 286Kb downloaded
>
> timeout: timedout